# Received Stock options as UK Employee, however exercised the stock as a Canadian Employee. What is my tax liability?

Tags: taxes, stocks, canada, united-kingdom, options

I work for a global company. As a UK resident, my company awarded me stock options & Restricted stock.  The stocks is traded on the NYSE.  I exercised the stock in Canada.  I transferred to the Canadian office, in which I'm a Canadian resident & citizen and exercised the stock.  What is the tax liability and where do I pay the taxes to?  the UK government or Canadian government?

Comment: What sort of scheme is this? Is it a HMRC approved one and if so which type.  You may well owe income tax and ni payments  to the UK Government on unapproved schemes

Answer (score 1):

Probably Canada, as you were in Canada when you exercised your options but if it is renumeration in connection with your employment in the UK, then HMRC could argue it is subject to UK tax.

Usually these types of transaction are constructed in such a way to reduce taxes.

You could always give HMRC a call and see what they suggest.  They're often surprisingly helpful with this type of thing.